# PHP: Query to display a link

Tags: php, sql, content-management-system

Hey guys hope someone can help with this.

I am using substr to give an abstract of articles. Now the problem is when you click the link to see the whole article you still see the substr version. Now this obviously happens because of the way the code is.

I need to make another query that will say if someone clicks the link then display the full article without the substr. I have no idea how to go about this can anyone help? While I am learning my PHP knowledge is fairly limited.

```
<?php
class MyCMS 
{
function get_content($id = "")
{
    if ($id != ""):
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE blog_id = '$id'";
        $return = '<p><a href="index.php"> Go Back To Content Page</a></p>';

    else:
        $sql = "SELECT blog_id, title, date, body FROM content ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";
    endif;

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) !=0):
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            echo '<div id="roundedbox"><h2><a href="index.php?id=' . $row['blog_id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . ' </a></h2>';
            echo '<div id="date"><h5><p>' . $row['date'] . '</p></h5></div>';
            echo substr('<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p>',0, 90)." .... "." read more </div>";
        }
        else:
            echo '<p> UH OOH! THERE IS NO SUCH PAGE IT DOES\'T EXIST </p>'; 
            echo $return;
        endif;  

}


}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another argument to the function to determine whether it returns the full article or an excerpt:

```
<?php
class MyCMS 
{
function get_content($id = "", $excerpt = FALSE)
{
    if ($id != ""):
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE blog_id = '$id'";
        $return = '<p><a href="index.php"> Go Back To Content Page</a></p>';

    else:
        $sql = "SELECT blog_id, title, date, body FROM content ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";
    endif;

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) !=0):
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            echo '<div id="roundedbox"><h2><a href="index.php?id=' . $row['blog_id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . ' </a></h2>';
            echo '<div id="date"><h5><p>' . $row['date'] . '</p></h5></div>';
            if ($excerpt):
                echo substr('<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p>',0, 90)." .... "." read more </div>";
            else:
                echo '<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p>';

        }
        else:
            echo '<p> UH OOH! THERE IS NO SUCH PAGE IT DOES\'T EXIST </p>'; 
            echo $return;
        endif;  

}


}
?>
```

Then when you are calling the get_content() function, pass it the id and excerpt flag as follows:

```
get_content(123, TRUE); //for excerpt
get_content(123); //for full post
```

Comment: hey thanks for getting back to me. Should i pass these values in here where i am call the class?

<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])):
    echo $obj->get_content($_GET['id']);
else:
    echo $obj->get_content();
    endif;
?>

Comment: yes, like `$obj->get_content($_GET['id'], TRUE)` for excerpt, `$obj->get_content($_GET['id'])` for full post

Comment: or if passing the flag via URL query string, `$obj->get_content($_GET['id'], $_GET['excerpt'])` and make your URL query string like `http://mydomain.com/myscript.php?id=123&excerpt=TRUE` for excerpt, `http://mydomain.com/myscript.php?id=123&excerpt=FALSE` for full post

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would encapsulate the article into a data class (alias "Model", see MVC architecture). This model holds all the data of the article and have a method to return the abstract or the long version of the article. To identify the version the client would like to see, pass another argument to your URL.

```
class Article {
    protected $text;
    protected $title;

    public __construct ($title, $text) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->text = $text;
    }        

    /** 
     * Returns the short excerpt of the article
     */
    public getShortAbstract () {
        // your substr() function
    }        

    /**
     * Returns the full article
     */
    public getText () {
        return $this->text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to do this with PHP, because when you're doing this with PHP you have to refresh the whole page.

I would advise you to use Javascript for this, like the jQuery library [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).

With this method, Google will still index all the content.